What MySQL configuration is required to enable performance_schema.variables_by_thread?
I am trying to read the performance_schema.variables_by_thread table with the following query, but it always returns an empty set:
mysql> select * from performance_schema.variables_by_thread limit 1;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

This is an active production server with hundreds of connections, so I think it is unlikely to actually be empty.
Is there some configuration flag that must be set to enable this functionality?
MySQL version information:
mysql> select version();
+-----------+
| version() |
+-----------+
| 8.0.35-27 |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Also, server greeting string:
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 107143716
Server version: 8.0.35-27 Percona Server (GPL), Release 27, Revision 2f8eeab2


what does select version show mysql 8 and above have lots  of rows

@nbk Added additional details about the server.

the standard mysql shows you the information, but percona has ts own implementation

You mean percona offers this information somewhere else, or percona does not offer this information at all?

Are you looking for SHOW SESSION VARIABLES;?

I'm trying to see the variables of all sessions, as described here:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/65144/can-you-see-other-users-session-variables-in-mysql
